# TypeError: "this is undefined" When using forEach on member array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class `marketData`:

```
export class marketData {
    id: number;
    denomCount: number;
    itemCount: number;
    conversionRates: Array<number> = [];
    conversionRateToLowest: Array<number> = [];
    itemPrices: Array<Array<number>> = [];
}
```

I would like to define a member function for it, `validate()`, that checks that the values of the class are set properly. I wrote part of this method to check `itemPrices`:

```
this.itemPrices.forEach(function(this, prices){
          if(prices.length != this.itemCount){
              // handle error 
          });
```

However, the above gives me a `ERROR TypeError: "this is undefined"`. I got the exact same error trying to check `itemPrices` in this manner:

```
this.itemPrices.forEach(function(prices){
          if(prices.length != this.itemCount){
              // handle error
          });
```

i.e. without the `this` in the `function` parameters.

What is the correct way to access the `itemCount` member variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of the the way you are using forEach. Use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead like below. And its recommended that when using typescript classes always use arrow functions else you will keep running into this problem.

```
this.itemPrices.forEach((prices) =>{
          if(prices.length != this.itemCount){
              // handle error
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` in the function is not the same as it is inside the class. You can either use fat arrow function or use `bind(this)` to bind the function to the class.

```
this.itemPrices.forEach(function(prices){
          if(prices.length != this.itemCount){
              // handle error
          }).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ES6's [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to access `this`. Anyways, do read [this](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8) up to udnerstand to context of `this` when it comes to JavaScript and using them within OOP in JS.

```
this.itemPrices.forEach((prices: number) => {
  if (prices.length != this.itemCount){
    // handle error 
  });
});
```